# GitLab and it's webhook for Build events

Tags: deployment, build, hook, gitlab

I've set up my own GitLab CE server with CI in it. I can already create a webhook to deploy my code to a server just by pushing it. (Many thanks to [Matt Jones](https://github.com/Muffinman) and his little [invention](https://github.com/orphans/git-deploy-laravel)).
However, I still have one issue there. I don't really find a very good description about GitlAbs new feature about Webhook for Build Events. I think I'll need this, since I wish to deploy my code **ONLY AFTER** a build was succesfull. If I set the webhook for push event, then it has no problem, inmediatly deploys the code. Can any of you provide me with a proper instruction, what do I have to make, to achieve my goal?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I use [jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) for these purposes, you can also set your preferences about when to deploy your code and run pre and post build steps. It's really useful and it has Gitlab integration with the Web hooks.

Comment: Yes, I also tried Jenkins, but after 2 months, I just couldn't make it do what I wished for. GitLab looks even nicer and that will make the management very happy too, not just the developers. :)

Comment: Oooh, ok, and why wasn't it useful anymore? What did you want to do? Hope you find an alternative anyway :)

Comment: Found it, GitLab. I wanted a handy, smart and responsive website for CI. Build my code for websites, test it with PHPUnit, Behat, etc and if it was all good, then deploy for a 3rd server. I know Jenkins can do these all, GitLab just looks more powerful. I just saw the tip of the iceberg, but I can see that there are more things to come for it. :)